# Convert the factor format of the data in the data into characters in R

Tags: r

Convert the factor format of the data into characters and numeric in R but something wrong there. Please help me to fix it.

[image]

```
data <-read.csv2('winequality-white.csv',header = T)
View(data)

head(data)
class(data)
data[,1:11]<-lapply(df[,1:11],as.character)
data[,1:11]<-lapply(df[,1:11],as.numeric)
```

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag and note, in particular, that code and input should NOT be provided as images but rather as text so that others can easily copy and paste it into their session to run it themselves.  At any rate, the code in the image is using `df` which is not defined so it will use R's  `df` which is a function to compute the F distribution density.

Comment: You are using `df[,1:11]` but your data.frame is named `data`. Since there is a _function_  named `df` you are trying to subset a function, which causes the _closure is not subsettable_  error.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe is called 'data' and not 'df'!

```
data[,1:11]<-lapply(data[,1:11],as.character)
data[,1:11]<-lapply(data[,1:11],as.numeric)
```